# python bisection code with google colab

Tags: bisection

I was using this code in google colab, and it keep give me a syntax error sign with this line **print intercept_bisection(f, 0.001)**, does anyone know what goes wrong?

```
# bisection method

def f(x):
    return -5+2*x

def intercept_bisection(func, epsilon):

    ''' func is a function
        epsilon is some small flaot
    '''
    low = 0
    high = 100
    mid = (high + low)/2.0

    while (abs(func(mid)) > epsilon):
           print("low = ", low, "high = ", high, "mid = ", mid)
           if func(mid) > 0:
               high = mid
           elif func(mid) < 0:
               low = mid
           mid = (high + low)/2.0
    return mid

print intercept_bisection(f, 0.001)
```

Answer (score 0):

You are using Python 2 syntax and most likely running Python 3.

In Python 3, 'print' is an ordinary function, and must have its argument inside parentheses.

Besides, when you ask about error messages, do show the exact error message, including line number.